# Get new RowVersion after Update EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, optimistic-concurrency

I am using EF Core with a dbContext that has a RowVersion set up for one of the entities. What I am trying to do is to update a list of objects using dbContext.Update(object). I then however want to return the newly updated objects with their new RowVersions without loading them all from the database again.

```
  using var dbContext = _dbContextService.CreateDbContext<DataFactoryDbContext>();

      var dataset = await dbContext.Datasets.Include(ds => ds.Fields)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(ds => ds.InstanceId == command.ClassificationId);

      var datasetFields = dataset.Fields.ToDictionary(t => t.InstanceId, t => t);

      foreach (var fieldViewModel in command.Fields) //Iterate through fields and check that the rowVersions match
      {
        var fieldModel = datasetFields[fieldViewModel.InstanceId];

        var rowVersion = fieldModel.RowVersion.ToBase64String(); 
        Assertion.RowVersionCheck(fieldViewModel.RowVersion, rowVersion, "At least one of the fields have changed since loading the screen. Please refresh and try again");
      }

      foreach (var fieldViewModel in command.Fields) //Iterate through fields and update sequences
      {
        var fieldModel = datasetFields[fieldViewModel.InstanceId];
        fieldModel.Sequence = fieldViewModel.Sequence;
        fieldModel.RowVersion = fieldViewModel.RowVersion.FromBase64String(); 

        var test = dbContext.DatasetFields.Update(fieldModel);

        var newViewModel = new DatasetFieldSlimViewModel()
        {
          RowVersion = test.Entity.RowVersion.ToBase64String() //Get new rowversion here maybe?
        };
      }

      await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
      return listOfNewViewModels //I need to return a new list of viewmodels with the Updated RowVersions without reloading the models from db;
    }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: cool edited now

Comment: Updated row versions, similar to identity and other store generated/calculated fields are available **after** calling `SaveChanges{Async}`

Comment: So the rowversions will have the updated values inside the models after the savechanges is called? Ie I dont now have to call into the dbContext again to fetch them

Comment: If you properly mapped it as rowversion column, yes. And if you did, you don't really need this explicit rowversion check. You'll get an optimistic concurrency exception on SaveChanges that you can catch and handle.

Comment: Perfect, that seems to be working. The explicit check is simply tied to our own logging system which ends up throwing the exception before any other transactional code happens. Ie before saveChanges. This code snippet was just a small part